# How to pass the Current Page Slug to Query's argument? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have these pages: Germany, Argentina, Brazil. When viewing any of these I need a Custom Loop that queries for News (Custom Post Type) AND queries for Country (Taxonomy).

The page slug is exactly as the taxonomy. How could i pass the page slug as a Variable and insert it as an argument inside a WP Query? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array

('post_type' => 'news',
'country' => $CurrentPageSlug,   //-------> HELP!
'posts_per_page' => 3)); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand i think you want to detect the page name, this is how you can do.

```
// Return the page name like Germany, Argentina, Brazil
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
```

Then pass this `$pagename` in [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) arguments.